# Symmetric PDF up to a proportionality

Tags: integration, expected-value, density-function

I have a random variable $X$ that has a pdf up to a proportionality defined by:
$$f(x) \propto e^\frac{-(x-1)^2}{ 2}+e^\frac{-(x-4)^2}{2} \quad 0<x<5$$

Also is given that the $E(X)=2.5$.It seems like there are two normal distributions there but how can I find the constant $c$ in order to calculate the expected value.

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$ and $x\gt 5$ it is NOT a normal distribution!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF $f(x) = c\left(e^{-(x-1)^2 / 2} + e^{-(x-4)^2 / 2} \right) \mathbf{1}_{(0, 5)}(x)$ is symmetric on $(0,5)$, meaning that $X$ has the same distribution as $-X+5$. To verify this, check that $f(x) = f(-x+5)$.

Knowing this, we can deduce $E[X] = E[-X+5]$ which gives $E[X]=2.5$ without needing to compute $c$. As far as I can tell, there is no simple expression for $c$ that avoids using the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: How $E(X)=2.5$?$\int xf(x)dx \neq 2.5$ for $f(x)=5-x$

Comment: @Tsiantakis I never said to do $f(x) = 5-x$. Check that $f(x) = f(-x+5)$ for any $x$; doing so will allow you to conclude that $X$ has the same PDF as $-X+5$. Therefore $E[X]=E[-X+5]$. Noting that $E[-X+5] = -E[X] + 5$ leads to $E[X] = -E[X] + 5$ which implies $2E[X] = 5$.

Comment: And why variance $$Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2= 2.0994$$ ?